# Slogan for a drapes manufacturer, which is correct? "Dressing the perfection" or "Dressing Perfection"?

Tags: nouns, articles

I work at a factory that manufactures drapes and window treatments, and we hired a marketing team to revamp our corporate identity.  The slogan they came up with is:

"Dressing the Perfection"

To me that sounds wrong, I believe it should be "Dressing Perfection".

They claim it's to give emphasis to the word "Perfection"  (As in ***the** perfection*).

Thoughts?

Comment: Personally, neither one makes sense. You can't really dress a "perfection" because perfection is a subjective idea and so the entire slogan is confusing and abstract.

Comment: I hope you didn't pay them much.

Comment: No article is better; with the definite article, it still works, it's still grammatical. However, it's too short a phrase for one to quickly grasp such a profound meaning. Think again.

Comment: @Kris It's arguable whether *the perfection* is grammatical without a clear referent. Nouns like that are usually zero-article, unless you're referring to something specific like *the water over there.*

Comment: @BraddSzonye That's no concern of grammar. And it's no sentence in the first place, it's a phrase for a slogan.

Comment: @Kris Article number agreement is surely as much a part of grammar as subject-verb number agreement or any other aspect of plurality, no? (And phrases have grammar too, even slogans. They are looser in some ways, but they err on the side of fewer articles, not more.)

Comment: No. (Lol, jk.) Think again.

Comment: @kris Could you please be less cryptic?

Answer (score 4):

Dressing perfection sounds more applicable, which is to say, perfection in the endeavour of dressing. In the same way you can have Engineering Perfection (which would mean an item of engineering that reflects the highest standards of perfection). Dressing the perfection sounds like a contrived attempt at personifying perfection. Would not recommend.

Sidenote:  From the comments on your question, you can see that it could easily cause confusion and consequently backfire spectacularly. You probably want to look for another slogan

Comment: +1 It isn't "more correct" (also, there's no such thing as "more" correct), the two versions mean slightly different things.